# How can I change the width of a column in a list view is SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, listview, sharepoint-2007

I have SharePoint 2007 and I have a list view that has a text field that, when shown with quite a few other fields, is only about 1 word narrow.

Is there a way to expand that column without access to css or other web programming languages?

Comment: Why no access to CSS or JavaScript? Do you have access to SharePoint designer?

Comment: @Kit Menke Nope.  [Comment concerning MIS dept redacted]. And that's all I have to say about that. ;0)

Comment: What about CSS/JavaScript? Can you deploy C# code to the server?

Comment: @Kit Menke No.  There is no way they will let that sort of thing go on.

Comment: @Keng - can you use Content Editor Web Parts (CEWP)?

Comment: @Ryan Well, everytime I try to Edit the web part it gives me an error that says "A Web Part you attempted to change is either invalid or has been removed by another user. " Though I just added it and no one is here to be doing anying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't use CSS, JavaScript, SharePoint Designer, or deploy any C# code to the server.. then you can't change the width of the column.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a ContentEditor Web Part with the CSS/JavaScript that sets the look of the column. You don't need C# or Designer.

I did something similar with a search page where I needed a JavaScript function to be triggered so I added a CEWP to the page with the following code (see below).

You could change this to look for the id of the column you want to modify.  Just remember that ID's of controls in SharePoint are generated during the page render so you won't necessarily know the exact ID.  That is why this code looks for an anchor with an ID that ends with '_PSB_Show', instead of looking for the exact ID.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var anchor;
var j; 

// Iterate through all anchors on the page and find the one with ID ending in _PSB_Show
for (j = 0; j < anchors.length; j++)
{
   if (anchors[j].id.match(/\_PSB_Show$/) != null)
   {
      anchor = anchors[j];
      break;
   }
} 

// If the anchor is found and the click is supported in the current browser
// Perform a click after 100 ms
if ((anchor != null) && (anchor.click != null))
{
   setTimeout("anchor.click();", 100);
}
</script>
```

Comment: If OP can use JavaScript or CSS, this is definitely the easiest way to go.

Comment: +1 ing this - I think the OP probably CAN put CSS/JS in a CEWP - just not modify any files using SPD etc.

Comment: Well, everytime I try to Edit the web part it gives me an error that says "A Web Part you attempted to change is either invalid or has been removed by another user. " Though I just added it and no one is here to be doing anying.